# Confusion in cut-off frequency of LTI System

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, frequency-response

Why cut-off frequency  is at (in figure given below) the frequency where $$|M(j\omega)|=0.707=1/√2(D.C gain)$$

But isn't cut-off frequency  according to its definition should be at frequency where $$ |M(j\omega)|= 1/√2(|Mr(j\omega)| )$$ as 3db from from peak determine the cutoff frequency?

[image]

Comment: -3dB from unity gain is customary ... maybe a graph where there's nothing at DC would make it necessary to use a mid-band value as a reference, but not the case here

Comment: If the peak is at +5 dB, the -3 dB relative to the peak will not make any sense.

Comment: Hi@a concerned citizen,so it means that cutoff frequency is not always gives Pmax/2 and its definition changes(as here we taken frequency where Pdc/2 occur) depending on type of filter?

Answer (score 2):

The shown fuction with a remarkable peaking within the passband looks like a Chebyshev-lowpass filter. For such a filter the cut-off frequency is commonly defined using the "ripple" and NOT the 3dB criterion.

That means: The end of the passband is defined at the point where the magnitude crosses the value for DC (in your case: "1") for the last time.

The 3dB criterion is applied for first-order filters and for all other responses without peaking near the pole frequency (without any ripple).

Comment: Hi @LvW ,so it means that cutoff frequency is not always gives Pmax/2 and its definition changes(as here we taken frequency where Pdc/2 occur) depending on type of filter ? And "all other responses without peaking near the pole frequency (without any ripple)" , I don't understand this sentence , could you please include one example for clarity ? Thanks!

Comment: The BUTTERWORTH response (also called: Maximally flat) starts at DC with Amax and the magnitude will never rise above Amax=Adc. It has a pole-Q of 0.7071 and a passband edge at Adc minus 3dB. For all other Q-values Qp>0.7071 there will be a ripple or a peak with values above the magnitude at DC. Hence: Amax>Adc. There is a common agreement that for those filters, the 3db criterion does NOT apply. Instead, the last crossing of the Adc value is used.